# Nginx : rewrite rule with multiple urls

Tags: nginx

Want to rewrite nginx with setup such as [www.example.com/abc/xyz/test/](http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/test/)

redirect to [www.example.com/abc/xyz/test.php](http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/test.php) So want to make an rewrite rule which will work for all pages with that url like so i tried this one which works

```
 location ~* /abc/xyz/.*/$
        {
            rewrite ^/abc/xyz/.*/$  /abc/xyz/test.php last;
        }
```

this rule works but it always redirect to test.php want to make it dynamic so that it will also work for test2.php test3.php when in url it will be like [www.example.com/abc/xyz/test2/](http://www.example.com/abc/xyz/test2/) and so on as we have 100 pages so i need to write 100 rules if no solution found.
Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

[`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) should be sufficient.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php;
}
```

Comment: in / we are using this to remove .php lines

    location / {
        try_files $uri  $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }



    location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }